# TimeActivity with .NET API v3 SDK

Tags: c#, .net, intuit-partner-platform

I can't get a time activity to save with the latest version of the .NET SDK and Quickbooks Online. I think it's the Employee Reference, but I just can't sort it out. Does the API even work right?

```cs
DataService commonService = new DataService(serviceContext);
string displayName = "Test Customer";
displayName = displayName.Replace("'", "\\'"); //Escape special characters
QueryService<Customer> customerQueryServiceXX = new QueryService<Customer>(serviceContext);
Customer resultCustomer = customerQueryServiceXX.Where(m => m.DisplayName == displayName).FirstOrDefault();

string employeeName = "First Last";
employeeName = employeeName.Replace("'", "\\'"); //Escape special characters
QueryService<Employee> customerQueryServiceEE = new QueryService<Employee>(serviceContext);
Employee resultEmployee = customerQueryServiceEE.Where(m => m.DisplayName == employeeName).FirstOrDefault();

string sfasdfasdfasdf = resultEmployee.FamilyName;

TimeActivity timeActivity = new TimeActivity();
timeActivity.BillableStatus = BillableStatusEnum.Billable;
timeActivity.BillableStatusSpecified = true;
timeActivity.Hours = 8;
timeActivity.Minutes = 0;
timeActivity.TxnDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
timeActivity.TxnDateSpecified = true;
//timeActivity.HourlyRate = new decimal(200);
//timeActivity.HourlyRateSpecified = true;
timeActivity.NameOf = TimeActivityTypeEnum.Employee;
timeActivity.NameOfSpecified = true;
timeActivity.CustomerRef = new ReferenceType()
{
    name = resultCustomer.DisplayName,
    Value = resultCustomer.Id
};
timeActivity.ItemRef = new ReferenceType()
{
    name = resultEmployee.DisplayName,
    Value = resultEmployee.Id,
};
timeActivity.Description = "Did something";
TimeActivity timeActivityResult = commonService.Add(timeActivity);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What does it say?

Comment: Please use request/response logging to get the details of the exact error in response files. Please correct the error by matching the xml against our docs for TiemActivity. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/logging

Answer (score 1):

ItemRef is for providing service Items. Please use timeActivity.AnyIntuitObject for specifying vendor or employee

```
timeActivity.NameOf = TimeActivityTypeEnum.Employee;
timeActivity.NameOfSpecified = true;
timeActivity.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType5.EmployeeRef;    
timeActivity.AnyIntuitObject= new ReferenceType()
{
    name = resultEmployee.DisplayName,
    Value = resultEmployee.Id,
};
```